# Neural network only predicts one class

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, image-classification

my model only predicts one class from binary class. The model takes a video input using Keras Video Frame Generator and get 350 frames for each video. The model must take an input sequences of 350 frames and outputs a binary class using BLSTM. The input shape is (350, 112, 75, 3). The batch size is 2 because of OOM error. I don't know if it could be the problem or there is something wrong in the code but the model seems learn nothing. This is the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPool2D, GlobalMaxPool2D
def build_convnet(shape=(112, 75, 2)):
    momentum = .9
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=shape, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))
    
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))
    
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))
    
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))
    
    # flatten...
    model.add(GlobalMaxPool2D())
    
    return model
```

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed, Dense, Dropout
def action_model(shape=(350, 112, 75, 3), nbout=2):
    # Create our convnet with (112, 75, 3) input shape
    convnet = build_convnet(shape[1:])
    
    # then create our final model
    model = Sequential()
    
    # add the convnet with (350, 112, 75, 3) shape
    model.add(TimeDistributed(convnet, input_shape=shape))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 512, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (NBFRAME, 112*75*3))))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    # Adding a second LSTM layer and Dropout layer
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 512, return_sequences = True)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    # Adding a third LSTM layer and Dropout layer
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 512)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nbout, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()
    return model
```

This is the model summary.

[image: img]

Comment: Did you shuffle your data on video basis (NOT frame basis)? (Assuming each of videos of 350 frames maps to one of the two classes). Without shuffling, the training will be biased.

Comment: I checked and printing the video indexes in the generator are in a random order

Comment: Ok, would you check the learning curve? Is it getting saturated very early (and the loss stopped decreasing at all)? If it is, then your model might be facing `Dying ReLU` problem. Try taking smaller learning rates and/or use some specialised weight initialization techniques like `He initialization`. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/HeUniform. You may also try other variations of `ReLU` like `Leakly ReLU`.

Comment: I tried to use smaller learning rate and Leakly ReLU: during training the model seems better both in training and validation set (70-80% accuracy) but it has 52% accuracy on test set.

Comment: Glad to know your problem is solved. But the problem you are facing now is different than the question's problem. You better ask a new question with code and most importantly with all the plots you generated. But for now I shall suggest you to verify the fact that -- if the train-data (at least the validation-data) a good representative of test data or not. To verify it you can ask yourself a small question -- If someone mixes up the test-data with train-data, will you be able to segregate them? If you can, then your train-data is not good. But if you can't then your train-data is okay.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are putting a lot of data in memory, have you tried reducing the number of frames for video? Does this help?

Comment: The number is already reduced, a little more and i might lose a lot of info

Answer (score 0):

Your model is too big, I'll remove this piece:

```
emodel.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum)) 
model.add(MaxPool2D())         
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))   
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))          
model.add(MaxPool2D())       
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))  
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum))
```

Maybe it causes oom, maybe you don't need it.